# How can I check the changes for the fields at form alter submit?

Tags: nodes, forms

I am using hook_form_alter() with custom submit handler (). 
At submit I want to check if there is any change in the content except node->expire then my custom code will run.

but at $form_state['value'] I am also getting: nid, vid, uid, created changed etc. 
and I have field type as ***taxonomy term reference*** and ***media files***.

I do not want to  hard-code the fields name as admin may add new fields later on.

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing both `$form_state[input]` and `$form_state['values']` .

After that check both values using the key's in foreach loop and compare both values, if changed then do your things there.

Comment: when I print value of taxonomy term reference for $form_state['input'] i get
[field_catagories]  => (
    [und] => Array
        (
            [31] => 31
            [34] => 34
            [22] => 
            [26] => 
        )

)
and when I print value of form_state['values'] my return value is
field_catagories => (
    [und] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [tid] => 31
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [tid] => 34
                )

        )

)
How to compare

Comment: Compare keys present then you will get 31 and 34 
These two values are your inputted values.